# How to add extension for xml file in Routing in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen

I need to load a sitemap from view folder and it's url should be **http://localhost:8000/nl/sitemap.xml** . So how can I set this sitemap with .xml extension in routing. This is what I am doing now.

**routes/web.php**

```
<?php


$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$fRouterConfig =  function () use ($router){
    $router->get('/', 'HomeController@show');
    $router->get('/client-cases','ClientCaseController@index');
 };
$fRouterConfignl =  function () use ($router){
  $router->get('/','NlController@index');
  $router->get('/service-models','NlController@serviceindex');
  $router->get('/sitemap.xml','NlController@sitemap');

};

$fRouterConfig();

$router->group(['prefix' => 'nl'], $fRouterConfignl);
$router->get('/testemail','MailController@sendMail');
$router->get('/load_twitter_feeds','TwitterController@Tweets');
$router->get('/{view_name}','SiteController@show');
$router->get('/nl/{view_name}','NlController@show');
```

Comment: Have you tried using `/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: I have already a sitemap.xml in my public folder and I can load the same without fail. I need to add one more sitemap and it's url should be nl/sitemap.xml. I can't create nl folder in public because nl is already set for routing so confilct occur.